# xquery compare 2 xml column for same element name

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2012, xquery

I have 2 xml columns in my SQL Server database, both with same structure but different data.

Like so:

1st column - `<root><Person>1</Person><Person>3</Person><Person>6</Person></root>`

2nd column - `<root><Person>2</Person><Person>3</Person><Person>6</Person></root>`

I need to compare by node name if any of the inner text values are common between these 2 columns. For the above eg., it should return true because person node has 3 and 6 in common.

I tried using xquery. I can compare the node to a specific value but not to another column like so:

```
select *
from t
where data.Person.exist('/Person[(text()[1]) eq "3"]') = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query will first use `.nodes()` to get all `<Person>` Numbers form the first XML, then use a corellated sub-query to get the second XML's values as a derived table which can be `INNER JOIN`ed. The result is a set reduced to the common numbers. You can group them by the row's ID column.

```sql
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, Xml1 XML, Xml2 XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('<root><Person>1</Person><Person>3</Person><Person>6</Person></root>'
 ,'<root><Person>2</Person><Person>3</Person><Person>6</Person></root>');

SELECT t1.ID
      ,p1.value('text()[1]','int')
FROM @tbl t1
CROSS APPLY t1.Xml1.nodes('/root/Person') A(p1)
INNER JOIN(SELECT p2.value('text()[1]','int') AS p2_Nmbr 
           FROM @tbl t2 
           WHERE t1.ID=t2.ID
           CROSS APPLY t2.Xml2.nodes('/root/Person') B(p2)) Tbl_p2 ON p1.value('text()[1]','int')=Tbl_p2.p2_Nmbr;
```

### UPDATE

This query will use a `CROSS APPLY` to combine both XMLs to one. With this combined XML you can run an `XQuery` first to get a distinct list of all IDs of the first and then check for common values:

```
SELECT * 
       ,BothXml.query(N'for $p1 in distinct-values(/persons[1]/root[1]/Person/text())
                              for $p2 in distinct-values(/persons[1]/root[2]/Person[text()=$p1]/text())
                              return $p2    
                       ') AS CommonIDs
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT t.Xml1 AS [*],t.Xml2 AS [*] FOR XML PATH('persons'),TYPE) A(BothXml);
```

There will be an empty result if there are no common IDs.

Comment: I was trying to avoid using cross apply.

Comment: @ShanShimb3o Why?

Comment: cross apply will convert the xml to sql columns and values. i wanted to find a way that xquery can directly do something. xquery should read through the xml and then spit out the comparison.

Comment: @ShanShimb3o, This is impossible, at least directly... Your XMLs are living in two different columns. `XQuery` does not support to include another XML into the *current* XML...

Comment: @ShanShimb3o ... *at least directly* ... See my update :-D

Comment: Yeah i dug through the xquery specifications and i figured out you cannot compare 2 xmls the way i was thinking. I will put your answer as the correct one. I think this is the best we can do in this type of scenario. Thanks for your help.